# In 28 Days Later, the infected lost cognitive ability -- but isn't there a scene where one can hear the infected speaking?

Tags: 28-days-later

In *28 Days Later* the head of the soldiers confidently (and rightly) predicts the end of the problem, because the infected become severely mentally impaired (even if they were merely enraged all the time, perhaps it would amount to the same thing, but they do seem, in the absence of uninfected, to go into a quiet state where they just lie around) and will never plant crops or do anything requiring planning.

But isn't there a scene where one of the infected speaks? IIRC, a youngster shouts something like "I hate you!", which is more consistent with being enraged rather than impaired (and enraged). I am not sure if that made it into a theatrical release, or I saw it in a trailer, or just read about it.

Comment: Given that you aren't sure if this scene is even in the final movie, perhaps it would be best to try and find the scene in question first.  There may be information given within the film to explain this, either in the scene itself or in surrounding scenes, assuming it's there at all.

Comment: @Steve-O  the thing about the kid talking i remember from years ago in an article. i can't recall any of the infected talking at all in the film versions i saw.

Comment: Perhaps the question is unclear then - are you asking us to find this article about a child infected speaking?  Or are you asking about an in-universe explanation for the event?

Answer (score 2):

I found [this wiki article](https://28dayslater.fandom.com/wiki/The_Infected#:%7E:text=But%20in%2028%20Days%20Later,night%20than%20during%20the%20day.&text=It%20is%20believed%20that%20the,whether%20or%20not%20they%20spoke.) which indicates that in the infected do not in fact speak and if there was speaking it was an accident or technical glitch. Of being diminished to the point where speech is not possible is consistent with both what we see of the infected close up (the chained soldier does not seem very rational) and the idea that they will starve to death because they will never grow crops, etc.